# How to suspend a backgrounded shell with a script?

Tags: shell, background-process, suspend, ash

Unfortunately I don't have a `suspend` command (busybox/ash). But I can use `kill -STOP $$` to return from a backgrounded shell (`sh &`) to the parent shell (and `fg` later).
But instead of typing this long kill-command I would like to write a script (named suspend) which should do this:

```
#!/busybox sh
kill --STOP $$
```

But this didn't work. It seems that I open another shell and suspend it  simultaneously.

So what is the right suspend-script and how do I call it (`exec`?)?

Comment: Great idea. You mean the suspend-script is `kill -STOP $$` only and I call it with `. /sbin/suspend`? I'm gonna try it.

Comment: That works in principle. But I have to type `. suspend` (starting with a dot and a blank). Isn't there a solution to type simply `suspend`?

Comment: Sorry for my late comments, you are typing faster than I do. Unfortunately I use ash and I don't  know if ash supports aliases in .ashrc (?). I'm gonna try but in principle I would like to do it without alias (simply typing a command).

Answer (score 1):

To sum up what I've written in the comments above:

The simplest way get a simple command for what you're trying to do is to make an alias in your `~/.profile` according to [this website](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=521770).

```
echo 'alias suspend=kill --STOP $$' >> ./~profile # Add alias to .profile
source ./~profile # Let ash update its list of aliases
```

Now you can use a short `suspend` command.

It might be difficult to do it using a script since a child process cannot easily (or at all) modify the environment of the parent.